# How do you properly pass data to a NSObject class for a collection view from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

How do you properly send data to a custom data NSObject class for a collection view? My variables are always returning as nil.

I have a splash screen in it's own view Controller. When all the data I want loaded has finished loading from firebase, I go to the main screen of the app via `performSegue(withIdentifier:)`, here's the code for the code in question from the `SplashScreenViewController`:

```
   func getDatabaseReference(){
    let d = DispatchGroup()
    d.enter()
    let encodedURL = (postIDRefDic["post1"]! + "/postURL")
    ref.child(encodedURL).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let newUrl = snapshot.value as! String
        DemoSource.shared.url = newUrl
        d.leave()
    })
    d.notify(queue: .main){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showHome", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

in the above code you can see that I'm seguing to my next view controller, `HomeViewController`, in the HomeViewController class I have a collection view which is helped by a custom class (the NSObject class) called `DemoSource` (also show above) that I'm using to assign the new data I just got in a variable within that class. This `DemoSource` class is a custom data class of type `NSObject`:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

struct DataObj {
    var image: UIImage?
    var play_Url: URL?
    var title = ""
    var content = ""
}

class DemoSource: NSObject {
static let shared = DemoSource()
var demoData = [DataObj]()
var url = ""

override init() {

    demoData += [
                  DataObj(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ss-1") , play_Url: URL(string: url), title: "title ", content: "Description")
    ]
}
```

}

I use this class with my HomeViewController with the collection view:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Firebase
import MMPlayerView


class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var offsetObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    lazy var mmPlayerLayer: MMPlayerLayer = {
    let l = MMPlayerLayer()
    l.cacheType = .memory(count: 5)
    l.coverFitType = .fitToPlayerView
    l.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    l.replace(cover: CoverA.instantiateFromNib())
    l.repeatWhenEnd = true
    return l
}()

@IBOutlet weak var playerCollect: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // remove previous download fails file
    MMPlayerDownloader.cleanTmpFile()
    self.navigationController?.mmPlayerTransition.push.pass(setting: { (_) in

    })
    offsetObservation = playerCollect.observe(\.contentOffset, options: [.new]) { [weak self] (_, value) in
        guard let self = self, self.presentedViewController == nil else {return}
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
        self.perform(#selector(self.startLoading), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.2)
    }
    playerCollect.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 200, right:0)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { [weak self] in
        self?.updateByContentOffset()
        self?.startLoading()
    }

        mmPlayerLayer.getStatusBlock { [weak self] (status) in
            switch status {
            case .failed(let err):
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "err", message: err.description, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            case .ready:
                print("Ready to Play")
            case .playing:
                print("Playing")
            case .pause:
                print("Pause")
            case .end:
                print("End")
            default: break
            }
        }
        mmPlayerLayer.getOrientationChange { (status) in
            print("Player OrientationChange \(status)")
        }
    }

deinit {

    offsetObservation?.invalidate()
    offsetObservation = nil
    print("ViewController deinit")
}

@IBAction func profileButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let uid = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
    let Splash = SpalshScreenViewController()
    Splash.GetProfilePicture(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetUsername(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetName(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetClipsNumber(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetFollowersNumber(uid: uid)
    Splash.GetFollowingsNumber(uid: uid)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showProfile", sender: nil)
}
}

extension HomeViewController: MMPlayerFromProtocol {
 func backReplaceSuperView(original: UIView?) -> UIView? {
    guard let path = self.findCurrentPath(),
        let cell = self.findCurrentCell(path: path) as? PlayerCell else {
        return original
    }
    return cell.imgView
}

// add layer to temp view and pass to another controller
var passPlayer: MMPlayerLayer {
    return self.mmPlayerLayer
}
func transitionWillStart() {
}
// show cell.image
func transitionCompleted() {
    self.updateByContentOffset()
    self.startLoading()
}
}
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let m = min(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
    return CGSize(width: m, height: m*0.75)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
    if self.presentedViewController != nil || self.mmPlayerLayer.isShrink == true {
            //self.playerCollect.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
            //self.updateDetail(at: indexPath)
        } else {
            self.presentDetail(at: indexPath)
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func updateByContentOffset() {
    if mmPlayerLayer.isShrink {
        return
    }

    if let path = findCurrentPath(),
        self.presentedViewController == nil {
        self.updateCell(at: path)
        //Demo SubTitle
        if path.row == 0, self.mmPlayerLayer.subtitleSetting.subtitleType == nil {
           }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate func presentDetail(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.updateCell(at: indexPath)
    mmPlayerLayer.resume()

    if let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController {
        vc.data = DemoSource.shared.demoData[indexPath.row]
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

fileprivate func updateCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = playerCollect.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PlayerCell, let playURL = cell.data?.play_Url {
        // this thumb use when transition start and your video dosent start
        mmPlayerLayer.thumbImageView.image = cell.imgView.image
        // set video where to play
        mmPlayerLayer.playView = cell.imgView
        mmPlayerLayer.set(url: playURL)
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func startLoading() {
    self.updateByContentOffset()
    if self.presentedViewController != nil {
        return
    }
    // start loading video
    mmPlayerLayer.resume()
}

private func findCurrentPath() -> IndexPath? {
    let p = CGPoint(x: playerCollect.contentOffset.x + playerCollect.frame.width/2, y: playerCollect.frame.height/2)
    return playerCollect.indexPathForItem(at: p)
}

private func findCurrentCell(path: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell? {
   return playerCollect?.cellForItem(at: path)
}
}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DemoSource.shared.demoData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell {
        cell.data = DemoSource.shared.demoData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
}
```

the first time I instantiate the `Demosource` class is:

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DemoSource.shared.demoData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as? PlayerCell {
        cell.data = DemoSource.shared.demoData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
}
```

When I run my app it crashes as apparently, the url in the data class is nil, even though I set it with the url in my splashscreenviewcontroller? This `DemoSource` class get's instantiated before the variable is even populated it seems, when I did some debugging with breakpoints.

So my question is, after all this explaining... why isn't the url variable in the `DemoSource` class still nil and why is the class getting executed before when the view that uses this class is only called AFTER the data has been fetched from Firebase?

Comment: `DemoSource.shared` is instantiated in `getDatabaseReference`. When the initialiser runs its `URL` property has its initial value "". Since it is a singleton instance the init never runs again and you won't add your actual URL to the `demoData` array.  You need to add at least one function to your model object (DemoData) if you want to be able to add items to that array.

Comment: Could you walk through that in an answer or something please, like add that function to my data class code and put that in your answer? I think I've tried what you're explaining but it only made matters worse, probably because I did it wrong...? I tried adding firebase logic to the class to but since it's only an NSObject class, I couldn't. I'm not that familiar or good with them...

Comment: Thank you though, that one comment is as far as I've gotten in two weeks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented `DemoSource` as a singleton, which means that it gets instantiated the first time that you reference `DemoSource.shared`.  This is in `getDatabaseReference`.  When it is instantiated `url` has its initial value (""), so that is what gets added to the the `demoData` array.

You don't need an initialiser.

You do need a function to add data to the `demoData` array.

```
class DemoSource: NSObject {
    static let shared = DemoSource()
    var demoData = [DataObj]()

    add(urlString: String) {
        demoData.append(DataObj(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ss-1") , play_Url: URL(string: urlString), title: "title ", content: "Description"))
    }
}
```

Then, in your `getDatabaseReference` -

```
func getDatabaseReference(){
    let d = DispatchGroup()
    d.enter()
    let encodedURL = (postIDRefDic["post1"]! + "/postURL")
    ref.child(encodedURL).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let newUrl = snapshot.value as? String {
           DemoSource.shared.add(urlString: newUrl)
        }
        d.leave()
    })
    d.notify(queue: .main){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showHome", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: would I need to change anything in my HomeViewcontroller class as my collection view uses it to get the data?

Comment: Not as it stands, because you are using the dispatch group to ensure that the HomeViewController isn't shown until after the data has been fetched.  However, you will have an issue if you expect more than one element in the `demoData` array as you will need to reload your collection view when the array is updated.  You can use a `Notification` or a delegation pattern on your model object or provide an update closure to your model or even use `Combine` to notify interested parties about changes to the model array.

Comment: So my script works and runs the `getDatabaseReference()` function from a for loop and gets whatever is in the database at the time. It could be one url or it could be 10 urls, at the moment if it's more than one url, then all the videos in the collection view are the same, im guessing thats the issue you're on about?

Comment: Yes.  You can put the dispatch group `enter` in the correct place so that you enter for each loop and then the `notify` only triggers when `leave` has been called the same number of times.  If your loop is somewhere outside of `getDatabaseReference` then the dispatch group needs to be outside that function too.

Comment: Yeah, I'll need to rewrite and clean up my code as the `getDatabaseReference` is called as soon as only one url has been populated. So ill try and do it so it only gets run once to for loop has completely finished.